# How to find the index value of the quartile values in an array using Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, quartile

I have a vector of dimension 1x3000. I have found the percentile value using the percentile function in Matlab. But I am unable to find the index value of the quartile inside the vector.

```
y = rand(1,3000);
Q_2 = prctile(y,50);
Idx = find(y==Q_2);
```

Idx is returning an empty value. I should be able to get a value of the index containing the median value.

Comment: You have an _even_ number of elements, so none of the elements is the median. The median is between the two "center" elements in the sorted vector. That's why you can't find it. Try size `3001` and you will

Comment: How should I find the nearest value to the median then? Is that possible?

Comment: Sort the vector and pick any of the two central values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can efficiently find the entry closest to the median (or an arbitrary `q_2` for that matter) with:

```
[~,Idx]=min(abs(q_2-y));
```

As per `help min`, the value returned as `Idx` corresponds to the *first* element with the minimum value in the vector of differences.